# How to turn off the antialiasing in TChart for Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, teechart

Does anyone know how to turn off the anti-aliasing in TChart for Firemonkey in Delphi XE2?

Comment: It has the anti-aliasing in Windows 7 which makes the application slow. And chart works fine in windows xp.

Comment: If that's the case you can probably change such settings either in Windows 7 or the GPU.

Comment: Try changing this parameters: GlobalUseHWEffects,  GlobalUseDirect2D, 
   GlobalUseGDIPlusClearType, GlobalDisableFocusEffect

Answer (score 1):

FireMonkey Canvas does not allow enabling or disabling anti-alias for individual controls.

It must be done at form level (starting with XE4), using the Form1.Quality property.