# TeeChart Lite FMX (RAD Studio XE8) anti-aliasing artifacts

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, antialiasing, teechart

I’ve got an issue with TeeChart Lite (RAD Studio XE8, FireMonkey).

[[image: picture]]

Grid width is ONE, but because of anti-aliasing, it became so fat.

I managed to hack it: when coordinates are (0.5, 0.5) averything is okay…

[[image: picture2]]

Looks good. But the hack works in designer only: in actual application nothing changes. Actually, the first image was shot with this hack.

Is there a way to fix it? Is it a hardware problem? Got an ATI Radeon HD 3200 graphic card.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off the antialiasing in TChart for Firemonkey?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672890/how-to-turn-off-the-antialiasing-in-tchart-for-firemonkey)

Comment: I don’t really want to turn it off. Just to fix these problems.

Comment: When you say "when coordinates are (0.5, 0.5) averything is okay", what coordinates do you mean? What properties should we set to see it?

Comment: Position.X and Y. If the control is aligned (like on the screenshot), make sure that width/height are integers (e.g. set parent’s paddings).

Comment: Please attach a simple example project we can open/run as-is to reproduce the problem here.